# Magento: Convert Quote to Order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I want to create order from quote id . I am using this code but order is not getting created

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(94251);
$convertQuote = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote'); 
$order = $convertQuote->toOrder($quote);
```

I get error that Credit card number mismatch with credit card type. payment method already store in quote. payment method is authnetcim.

Comment: pls try my answer and let me know it works or not.

Comment: Anyone have solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below :

```
$store = Mage::getSingleton('core/store')->load(1);

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStore($store)->load(94251);
$quote->assignCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());

$quote->collectTotals()
    ->getPayment()->setMethod('purchaseorder');

$convert = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote');
$order = $convert->toOrder($quote)
    ->setBillingAddress(
        $convert->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getBillingAddress())
    )
    ->setShippingAddress(
        $convert->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getShippingAddress())
    )
    ->setPayment(
        $convert->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment())
    );

foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
    $orderItem = $convert->itemToOrderItem($quoteItem);
    if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
        $orderItem->setParentItem(
            $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($quoteItem->getParentItem()->getId())
        );
    }
    $order->addItem($orderItem);
}

$order->save();
```

Comment: it not works. no any order createa

Comment: and i not want to store any static information when create order

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(5428);

$convert = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_quote');

$order = $convert->toOrder($quote);
$order->addressToOrder($quote->getAddress(),$order);

foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
    $orderItem = $convert->itemToOrderItem($item);
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
       $orderItem->setParentItem($order->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId()));
    }
    $order->addItem($orderItem);
}

$quote->getShippingAddress()->setPaymentMethod('paypal_express');
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);

$payment = $quote->getPayment();
$payment->importData($data);
$quote->save();

$payment = $convert->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment());

$order->setPayment($quote->getPayment());

$message = '[Notice] - Order converted from quote manually';
$order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(), $message);
$order->place();
$order->save();

$quote->setIsActive(false)->save();
```

Other solution:-

Have you tried the toOrder Method?

http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Quote.html#toOrder

EDIT :-

```
$convertQuote = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote'); $order = $convertQuote->toOrder($quote);
```

Comment: in quote there is all information store already. so no any static info store.

Comment: Your "other solution" is just the beginning bit of your main solution. It's also the same as what jigs tried already, as shown in his question.

Comment: And where does `$data` come from in the line `$payment->importData($data);`?